# How can I install Firebird 4.0 version on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firebird, firebird-4.0

I need to install Firebird 4.0 version on Ubuntu. When I installed Firebird like that:

```
 sudo apt-get install firebird-server
```

I noticed that it was 3.0 version. Then I uninstalled it. How can I install 4.0 version on terminal?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Ubuntu doesn't package Firebird 4.0 (and I'm not sure if they have plans to do so in the future). You could try the package from the Firebird site, or try to compile from sources. In any case, your question is not really on-topic here, as it is not a programming question. Consider asking on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support

Comment: Consider trying the instructions on [How to install Firebird 3.0 and 4.0 on Linux](https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/how-to-install-firebird-3-0-and-4-0-on-linux)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i'm gonna ask on Google.